# JDBC Unable to get managed connection

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jakarta-ee, jdbc, jboss

I have been experiencing some problems with a Web App recently, I have a MDB (HornetQ) setup that consumes health messages from a number of remote nodes (standalone Java applications), as we have steadily increased the number of nodes that are reporting in we have start to have problems with the Web Application losing its database connection, checking the log files and upon receiving a message the following error is reported:

```
2014-04-23 06:38:37,094 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (Thread-100 (group:HornetQ-client-global-threads-32102134)) Unable to get managed connection for webAppDatasource; - nested throwable: (javax.resource.ResourceException: Unable to get managed connection for webAppDatasource)
```

Once this happens our whole web application is unusable as the database does not allow anymore connections and I have to login to the JBoss Admin Console, pause the queue, clear the backlog and then restart PostgreSQL

I initially thought that the application was taking too many connections and I added 3CP0 to pool them but this doesn't seem to have helped (using the default settings), I have also moved our database onto a separate server to help with any performance bottlenecks and have added the 'autoReconnect' and 'check-valid-connection-sql' attributes to the datasource config as follows:

```
<datasources>
    <local-tx-datasource>
        <jndi-name>webAppDatasource</jndi-name>
        <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://10.123.123.23:5432/MainDb</connection-url>
        <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
        <autoReconnect>true</autoReconnect>
        <check-valid-connection-sql>select count(*) from admin_users</check-valid-connection-sql>
        <failOverReadOnly>false</failOverReadOnly>
        <maxReconnects>50</maxReconnects>
        <initialTimeout>15</initialTimeout>
        <user-name>jboss</user-name>
        <password>*****</password>
    </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

On average the application seems to use about 4 / 5 connections which doesnt seem too excessive.

The MDB itself is quite simple and parses the message, performs some checks against the database and persists the contents to a few different tables, there are about 60 nodes producing 1 message every 120sec so its possible that the application/database is getting overwhelmed at certain points

So my question is, can anyone suggest why the datasources would just lose their connections and are there any steps I can take to prevent this from happening?

Thanks

(I am using the postgresql-9.0-802.jdbc4 driver, PostgreSQL 9.0, Hibernate 3.6, JBoss AS 6)

Update: Stacktrace below,

```
2014-04-23 06:48:39,886 ERROR [org.quartz.core.JobRunShell] (JBossQuartzScheduler_Worker-7) Job default.job.10.1398215092090 threw an unhandled Exception: : javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
        at $Proxy328.findById(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor603.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:32)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.ClientSideInterceptor$1.proceed(ClientSideInterceptor.java:76)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
        at org.jboss.seam.security.SecurityInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:163)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
        at org.jboss.seam.ejb.RemoveInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RemoveInterceptor.java:43)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.ClientSideInterceptor.invoke(ClientSideInterceptor.java:54)
        at org.javassist.tmp.java.lang.Object_$$_javassist_seam_9.findById(Object_$$_javassist_seam_9.java)
        at uk.co.webapp.actions.scheduled.ScheduledActionsBean$7.execute(ScheduledActionsBean.java:254)
        at org.jboss.seam.security.Identity.runAs(Identity.java:743)
        at org.jboss.seam.security.RunAsOperation.run(RunAsOperation.java:75)
        at uk.co.webapp.actions.scheduled.ScheduledActionsBean.ustdCompleter(ScheduledActionsBean.java:348)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1836.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeTarget(MethodInvocation.java:122)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.container.ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.invokeNext(ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.java:72)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor$InvocationContext.proceed(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:127)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.EJBInvocationContext.proceed(EJBInvocationContext.java:44)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
        at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:28)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
        at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:77)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
        at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
        at org.jboss.seam.persistence.EntityManagerProxyInterceptor.aroundInvoke(EntityManagerProxyInterceptor.java:29)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
        at org.jboss.seam.persistence.HibernateSessionProxyInterceptor.aroundInvoke(HibernateSessionProxyInterceptor.java:30)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:50)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor554.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.EJB3InterceptorInterceptor.invoke(EJB3InterceptorInterceptor.java:80)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.EJB3InterceptorInterceptor.invoke(EJB3InterceptorInterceptor.java:71)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.container.ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.invokeNext(ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.java:62)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.invoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:76)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.aroundInvoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor455.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.aop.advice.PerJoinpointAdvice.invoke(PerJoinpointAdvice.java:174)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.fillMethod(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:74)
        at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_12864763.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_12864763.java)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.setup(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:90)
        at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_12864763.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_12864763.java)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.async.impl.interceptor.AsynchronousServerInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousServerInterceptor.java:128)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:62)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:56)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:68)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.core.context.SessionInvocationContextAdapter.proceed(SessionInvocationContextAdapter.java:95)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:223)
        at $Proxy304.ustdCompleter(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1835.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:32)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.ClientSideInterceptor$1.proceed(ClientSideInterceptor.java:76)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.ClientSideInterceptor.invoke(ClientSideInterceptor.java:54)
        at org.javassist.tmp.java.lang.Object_$$_javassist_seam_20.ustdCompleter(Object_$$_javassist_seam_20.java)
        at uk.co.webapp.actions.scheduled.UstdCompleter.execute(UstdCompleter.java:38)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1844.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeTarget(MethodInvocation.java:122)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.container.ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.invokeNext(ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.java:72)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor$InvocationContext.proceed(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:127)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.EJBInvocationContext.proceed(EJBInvocationContext.java:44)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
        at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:28)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
        at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:77)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
        at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:118)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:50)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor554.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.EJB3InterceptorInterceptor.invoke(EJB3InterceptorInterceptor.java:80)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.EJB3InterceptorInterceptor.invoke(EJB3InterceptorInterceptor.java:71)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.container.ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.invokeNext(ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.java:62)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.invoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:76)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.aroundInvoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor455.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.aop.advice.PerJoinpointAdvice.invoke(PerJoinpointAdvice.java:174)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.fillMethod(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:74)
        at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_12864763.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_12864763.java)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.setup(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:90)
        at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_12864763.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_12864763.java)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.async.impl.interceptor.AsynchronousServerInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousServerInterceptor.java:110)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:62)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:56)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:68)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.core.context.InvocationContextAdapter.proceed(InvocationContextAdapter.java:70)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:223)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:353)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.invoke(CMTTxInterceptor.java:209)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.aop.CMTTxInterceptorWrapper.invoke(CMTTxInterceptorWrapper.java:52)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.java:79)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.invoke(BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.java:67)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.core.context.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:47)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationInterceptor.java:67)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.EJB3TCCLInterceptor.invoke(EJB3TCCLInterceptor.java:86)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.MessagingContainer.localInvoke(MessagingContainer.java:306)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.inflow.MessageInflowLocalProxy.delivery(MessageInflowLocalProxy.java:299)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.inflow.MessageInflowLocalProxy.invoke(MessageInflowLocalProxy.java:152)
        at $Proxy257.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.quartz.inflow.QuartzJob.execute(QuartzJob.java:57)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1214)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:635)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:589)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor605.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.seam.persistence.EntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(EntityManagerInvocationHandler.java:46)
        at $Proxy371.find(Unknown Source)
        at uk.co.webapp.dao.generic.GenericDAOBean.findById(GenericDAOBean.java:93)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor604.invoke(Unknown Source)
        ... 222 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1700)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:801)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2037)
        at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:86)
        at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:76)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3268)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:496)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:477)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:227)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:285)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:152)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1090)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:1005)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:998)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:614)
        ... 271 more
Caused by: org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: Unable to get managed connection for webAppDatasource; - nested throwable: (javax.resource.ResourceException: Unable to get managed connection for webAppDatasource)


        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:95)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:71)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
        ... 289 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: Unable to get managed connection for webAppDatasource
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.getManagedConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:441)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManager.java:414)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:496)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2$ConnectionManagerProxy.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:941)
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:89)
        ... 291 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: No ManagedConnections available within configured blocking timeout ( 30000 [ms] )
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:310)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool$BasePool.getConnection(JBossManagedConnectionPool.java:747)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.getManagedConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:403)
        ... 295 more
```

Comment: With this configuration, the maximum connections in the pool is 20; you need to explicitly set `max-pool-size` to another number if you want to increase the size of the pool. I am not sure how you tried to utilize c3p0, but that usually makes no sense if you use the JBoss datasources, as those are connection pools themselves.

Comment: Hi Mark, I am not trying to increase the available pool size as this doesn't seem to be the problem (the no. connections seems to stay around 4/5), my problem is that the connections are getting lost somehow (use of c3pO is probably irrelevant)

Comment: Average connection use is not the same as peak connection usage. You currently only display the exception message, maybe posting the full stacktrace will provide more detail.

Comment: First thing to do is look at the *full exception text* with complete stack trace. Post it here if possible.

Comment: Sure, I have added a full stacktrace, this is coming from a quartz task that is performs some background tasks and is expecting a database connection

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This exception indicates that the connection pool is exhausted (most likely because all available connections are in use):

```
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: No ManagedConnections available within configured blocking timeout ( 30000 [ms] )
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:310)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool$BasePool.getConnection(JBossManagedConnectionPool.java:747)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.getManagedConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:403)
```

You either need to increase the `max-pool-size` of the JBoss connection pool (default is 20) as I suggested earlier in the comments, or you need to check if you are leaking connections (ie: not explicitly closing them).

Comment: Right ok, I did check the number shortly after it happened and it showed 4 connections perhaps they were released after the exceptions? Is there any way to view this data historically?

Comment: @DaveB I believe there are JMX tools that can read this information and make graphs, don't know the specifics though.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, after further investigation I think it may be my cron tasks that were backing up and taking all the connections, after disabling these the problem has gone away